# connecting to access database adjusts the size of the winform C#

Tags: c#, database-connection, ms-access-2013

[Before Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQK3B.png)
[After Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrXtY.png) 
I apologize if this question has already been addressed... I could not find it.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Professional.  The issue that i am having is when i connect to an Access Database the size of my WinForm shrinks when Debugging.  If i comment out the line that connects to the Access Database the WinForm is back to normal size when Debugging.

Has anyone else had this issue?  Does anyone know a fix for this?

Here is a code snippet...

```
 public partial class FormAdmin : Form
    {
        String conn_string = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
        String Error_Msg = "";
        String q = "";
        OleDbConnection conn = null;

        public FormAdmin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //FormAdmin Load
        private void FormAdmin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                conn = new OleDbConnection(conn_string);
                conn.Close();
                conn.Open();
                label8.Text = "connection to database successful" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: its been a couple days... its looking like i am actually having issues with debugging in general.  I am using VS 2015 PRO with Windows 10.  When the form loads it is not in the same graphical configuration as i created it in.

Comment: I have realized that it doesn't have to do with connecting to a database.  It is  just the way it debugs in Windows 10.

Comment: This plagued me for a long time but I think it also had to do with the tablet mode settings on the laptop I was using at the time.